# Is it possible to forget your mother tongue?

Tags: translation, spoken-english, learning

Is it possible to think in English without translating? Someone who learned English, Is it possible to think in English this person? to be like mother tongue or like a baby born in America.

Comment: I'm sure it's POSSIBLE. There are people who forget their own names. If someone moved to another country where no one spoke his native language and lived there for 50 years, could he forget his native language? Anybody have personal knowledge of such a case? I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: The questions in the title and body are significantly different.

Comment: I know snailboat. :) I'm sorry . I cannot fully express my mind. and Jay I think possible.

Comment: I wouldn't use the word *forget*, or even *attrition*. To me, it's more like *temporary suppression*, or *putting aside*. I think it depends on a lot of factors and could vary from person to person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know from personal experience that, after living and working in Germany for four years (with a good knowledge of the language when I arrived), I read newspapers and books and enjoyed films without translating into my native English. I don't *think* I had any thoughts in English When I spoke with German colleagues, but it is difficult to be absolutely certain. A German colleague, who was married to an Englishman and had lived and worked in England for twenty years, told me that her thoughts were completely in English when she used that language. So, the answer to your question is probably 'yes'.

Comment: You're right and in my opinion yes. Because sometimes I learned new words taking the place of the word in my native language and I found it : http://archive.news.softpedia.com/news/The-Human-Brain-Must-Forget-the-Mother-Tongue-When-Learning-a-New-Language-44828.shtml

Comment: Yes, but only temporarily; when I'm back in England, after a day or two it all comes back. I mean, I can speak English any time, but I'm searching for words if I only learned to name the thing in German. Katalysator, Ummelden...